# Looking for Guidance for External Native TCP Service Fabric Client

Tags: external, azure-service-fabric, tcpclient

I have a number of native TCP-based Service Fabric applications running in both stateless and stateful modes. I've been experimenting the creating a custom external SF client implementation using native TCP via RPC calls. As the SF Service can push data down to clients we need a persistent connection. I've been playing with ICommunicationClient and ServicePartitonClient and that seems clear enough; however, I am looking for some guidance regarding how to best handle the "ValidateClient" method in my implementation of CommunicationClientFactory. I've studied this reference quite a bit: [Communication clients and factories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication#communicating-with-a-service); we already have a working TCP Client that works less service fabric. My thinking is that I just need to use the SF Client SDK to get a secure connection to the ServicePartiton and the exposed TCP endpoint. I hope that members of the Microsoft SF team or any knowledgable person can point me to other resources; this terribly exciting stuff - I hope there is a way forward.

Comment: [This](https://dzimchuk.net/implementing-a-rest-client-for-internal-communication-in-service-fabric/) is for internal communication inside a cluster, but maybe this help.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts - thanks for the reference; I had already come across the blog posting; the devil is in the details and so with this particular TCP integration things are a bit more involved - but, there is enough there for good guidance.

Comment: I did find that if you have a TCP client and you need to connect directly to your TCP Server in an SF Cluster you can do so by configuring the Azure Load Balancer.